# Continous syntax error at the end of the code

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, syntax-error

I don't understand why the syntax error is being prompted at the last bracket. No matter how I rearrange the code, the error seems to have stuck at the end of the code and doesn't go away. There are two errors shown. 1st: Insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration. 2nd: Insert "}" to complete ClassBody. If anyone can please help me figure out? Thanks!
 `

```
public class AKMainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String ACTIVITIES = "activities";
    private Spinner spinner1;
    private EditText ETinfo;
    private SharedPreferences savedActivities;
    private ArrayList<String> details;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_akmain);

        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String[] items = new String[]{"Walking", "Running", "Stairs", "Generic"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
        dropdown.setPrompt("Select Activity");

        ETinfo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETinfo);

        savedActivities = getSharedPreferences(ACTIVITIES, MODE_PRIVATE);

        details = new ArrayList<String>(savedActivities.getAll().keySet());
        Collections.sort(details, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

        public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                addDetailedActivity(ETinfo.getText().toString());
                ETinfo.setText("");
            }
            }
```

Comment: Check your curly braces for each open curly brace there should be a close curly brace.

Comment: I already verified all open and close braces though, they seem to be all fine?

Comment: You are missing a } bracket and there is a ` at last.Remove it first

Comment: If it ask for a `;` or an extra `}`, then it's because your braces are mismatched. Any good IDE or text editor will be able to show you matching braces. Learn to use that feature of your IDE/editor.

Comment: @Khan They are not fine. I see 4 `{`, but only 2 `}`, not counting the `String[]` initializer. At the end of the code you've shown, you are still inside the `onCreate` method.

Comment: I needed to put a semi-colon at the end of the last brace. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You are defining an inner class, and are missing a semi-colon. I would also recommend the [`@Override` annotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html). Something like,

```
public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addDetailedActivity(ETinfo.getText().toString());
        ETinfo.setText("");
    }
}; // <-- to close OnClickListener
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

The error message is given because you are missing or having an extra brace. Try adding a brace '}' at the end of the code and if the problem persists try removing it and one more brace. The brace act like limiters and delimiters for the code. If not given properly, the code would face compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

you have at the end of the code something like:

```
public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                addDetailedActivity(ETinfo.getText().toString());
                ETinfo.setText("");
            }
            }
```

this is called anonymous class and is in fact another statement that must be

ended wwith semicolon,

```
public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                addDetailedActivity(ETinfo.getText().toString());
                ETinfo.setText("");
            }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class a extends Activity {

    private static final String ACTIVITIES = "activities";
    private Spinner spinner1;
    private EditText ETinfo;
    private SharedPreferences savedActivities;
    private ArrayList<String> details;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_akmain);

        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String[] items = new String[]{"Walking", "Running", "Stairs", "Generic"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
        dropdown.setPrompt("Select Activity");

        ETinfo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETinfo);

        savedActivities = getSharedPreferences(ACTIVITIES, MODE_PRIVATE);

        details = new ArrayList<String>(savedActivities.getAll().keySet());
        Collections.sort(details, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

        public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                addDetailedActivity(ETinfo.getText().toString());
                ETinfo.setText("");
            }
        };

    }
    }
```

Try this.You had to insert a semicolon since onClicklistener is a localvariable declaration statement.